# Auto Animate.css height for Flex Box SlideIn

Tags: javascript, animate.css

I'd like to use animate.css to slide my content out when I toggle the display upon title clicks.

Here's what I currently have:

```
*/ With Animate.css /*
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rgLf0mhv/

And here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
*/ With jQuery /*
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cm7a9jr7/

How can I achieve this effect with Animate.css (or vanilla CSS) ?

Comment: you can add a class on click that applies styles, thats all animate.css is doing.  you cannot animate `height: auto;` so you will have to set a fixed height to animate with css

Comment: @TylerFowle is there a lighter animation library than jQuery that easily achieves this auto-sized slide effect?  The height varies by the amount of content, so it's inherently a non-fixed sized element.  I've seen hacks that set a large max-height, but this ends up delaying the effect. (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

Comment: check out velocity.js http://velocityjs.org/

Comment: @TylerFowle I think that's going to be the best solution.  Thanks!